# creating/formatting string of hex values for serial device

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I am working with some old Python code on 2.7, sending and receiving data to a FTDI device via python serial library.

The hex data is sent escaped in a bytes literal string  for example
`ser.write(b"\x02\x27\x01")` the response is coming back in a similar format.

I have a function that calculates a passcode and I need to get a response sent in a string format. `b"\xnn"` where nn is a hex Value.

So trying to craft the response in the following manner (the code was part of the existing program), that is failing

Where

```
high = 0x54
low = 0xd3

key_answer="\x04\x27\x02"+chr(int(high)).encode('latin1')+chr(int(low)).encode('latin1')
```

It fails with the following:

```
Message='ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I just use the `chr()` function I get
`"\x04'\x02**T**\xd3"`  where the high value should be `\x54` and not the char `T`.

So the question is: How do I force the formatting of hex values from a `0a54` format to the string literal `'\x54'`?

Comment: Python 2.7 tries to be "helpful" and convert bytes to strings and vice versa when you mix the two.  It does so using the ASCII codec, which is almost always the wrong choice.  To fix this be consistent about using bytes and strings.  `chr(x)` creates a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use my codec [`all-escapes`](https://pypi.org/project/all-escapes/), it's designed for exactly this use-case.

```
pip install all-escapes
```

Simplest demo:

```
>>> b"T".decode("all-escapes")
"\\x54"
```

Full usage example for your case:

```
>>> key_answer = b"\x04\x27\x02"
>>> b = bytearray(key_answer)
>>> b.extend([high, low])
>>> print(b)
bytearray(b"\x04\'\x02T\xd3")
>>> print(b.decode('all-escapes'))
\x04\x27\x02\x54\xd3
```